# How to add a DTD to XML Catalog in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, dtd, xmlcatalog

I try to add a DTD created by myself to the XML Catalog in Eclipse. 
Which values do I have to enter into the fields?
Where do I have to locate the DTD in best case?

I have multiple Java projects in my Eclipse IDE. So what would be the best practice to make the DTD accessible for all projects?

I tried to use *Window-->Preferences-->XML-->XML Catalog-->Add* to get a catalog entry under *User Specified Entries*.
Currently it looks like this:

```
Entry element:      System
Location:           cc-utils-test-db-3.1-SNAPSHOT/src/main/resources/cc_dataset.dtd
URI:                platform:/resource/cc-utils-test-db-3.1-SNAPSHOT/src/main/resources/cc_dataset.dtd
Key type:           System ID
Key:                dataset file:////services/utils/test-db/src/main/resources/cc_dataset.dtd
```

Referencing the DTD in the XML file, Eclipse complains:

`No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document`.

and

```
The file cannot be validated as the XML definition "C:\develop\Projects\...\ws\services\utils\test-db\src\main\resources\globaltestdata\cc\cc_dataset.dtd (The system can't find the specified file)" that is specified as describing the syntax of the file cannot be located.
```

(I have partially translated from German into English.)

How do I have to make the XML Catalog entry that the DTD can be referenced (in best case over all projects in Eclipse IDE) to validate the XML file when using

```
<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "cc_dataset.dtd">
```

in it.

Where should be to DTD located (in the filesystem) to make it best accessible?

I changed my XMLC atalog entry:

```
Entry element:      System
Location:           cc-utils-test-db-3.1-SNAPSHOT/src/main/resources/cc_dataset.dtd
URI:                platform:/resource/cc-utils-test-db-3.1-SNAPSHOT/src/main/resources/cc_dataset.dtd
Key type:           System ID
Key:                ccdataset
```

The reference in the XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE dataset SYSTEM "ccdataset">
```

Eclipse's reaction:

```
The file cannot be validated as the XML definition "C:\develop\Projects\EOBR\ws\services\utils\test-db\src\main\resources\globaltestdata\cc\ccdataset (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)" that is specified as 
 describing the syntax of the file cannot be located.
```

cc_dataset.dtd is located at C:\develop\Projects\EOBR\ws\services\utils\test-db\src\main\resources\ i don't know why Eclipse extends this to the path of the XML file with the  declaration.

Comment: Try making your key in the catalog just "cc_dataset.dtd"

Comment: Eclipse complains... Warning: the key value should be a fully qualified URI 
...and in fact it doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: I think the key has to match the value specified in the doctype.

Comment: I changed the XML Catalog entry and the XML <!DOCTYPE...> declaration as you can see above.